# javascript option select problem

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, html-select

I got this javascript code from off the internet. It's a script that changes a picture and it caption from the selection of an options drop down box. The script works fine. The only problem that I have is that the value in the option box can only be numbers. Is there anyway to tailor this whereas the value within the options parameter can be words instead of numbers? Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
img{
height:200px;
width:250px;
display:block;
margin-top:10px;
}
#caption{
font-family:Verdana,tahoma,arial;
font-size:10pt;
text-align:center;
display:block;
width:250px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
/************************************************************
* Script by : Raymond Angana
* Title: Dropdown Based Picture w/ Captions
* First seen in AFHB2000.com
* rangana in AHFB2000.com
* Created June 5, 2008
* This notice must stay intact
/**********************************************************/
window.onload=function()
{
    var caption=['Default Image Caption',
                'Caption1',
                'Caption2',
                'Caption3',
                'Caption4',
                'Caption5',
                'Caption6',
                'Caption7',
                'Caption8',
                'Caption9'], // This will be your images caption
    bp='http://h1.ripway.com/rangana/images/', //base url of your images
    imgnum=14, //Number of your images. This should match on your comboboxes options.
    thumb=document.getElementById('thumb'), //id of your image that will be changing
    description=document.getElementById('caption'), //id of your caption
    combobox=document.getElementById('selection'); // id of your combobox.

    combobox.onchange=function()
    {
    thumb.src=bp+'Picture'+this.value+'.jpg';
    description.innerHTML=caption[this.value];
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<label>Please Change the default picture: </label>
<select id="selection">
<option>Change Picture</option>
<option value="1">Image 1</option>
<option value="2">Image 2</option>
<option value="3">Image 3</option>
<option value="4">Image 4</option>
<option value="5">Image 5</option>
<option value="6">Image 6</option>
<option value="7">Image 7</option>
<option value="8">Image 8</option>
<option value="9">Image 9</option>
</select>
<br>
<img src="http://h1.ripway.com/rangana/images/Picture1.png" alt="mypic" id="thumb">
<span id="caption">Caption for the default Image</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value attribute can be text, it doesn't have to be a number.  The only thing that will break in the above code is:

```
description.innerHTML=caption[this.value];
```

You can replace that to be:

```
description.innerHTML = caption[this.selectedIndex]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason why you'd want to have the word in the option value, if you have word there then it would be difficult to get the caption.

If the goal is to get the image specific to selected option and if you want to put your own image name instead of 'Picture'+id, I would modify like below.

In `onLoad` change captions array as below (add more options and corresponding images):

```
var appimages=[['Caption1','image1.gif'],['Caption2','image2.gif']];
```

And in `onChange` function change as below:

```
thumb.src=bp+appimages[this.value][1];
description.innerHTML=appimages[this.value][0];
```

Hope this helps.